# MomentJS String + Formats does not work

Tags: momentjs

I am not able to validate the given date. I have multiple time formats options.

```
moment("10/4/2013 01:00",["DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss", "DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"]).isValid();
```

However it is valid when,

```
moment("10/4/2013 01:00",["MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm"]).isValid();
```

It becomes invalid again when I add a three letter month format

```
moment("10/4/2013 01:00",["DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm", "MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"]).isValid();
```

The two formats in the line above are totally different however `moment` is not parsing the date.

I want to validate the date in either formats.

Comment: Appears to be a bug and looks like you (or someone else) already logged it [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1165).

Comment: I did. Thanks for the reply at both places.

Answer (score 1):

This is a  known issue 1133 in [github](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1133).

Answer (score 0):

validation with multiple formats seems to check if string is valid in every format.

I would simply do a function to iterate on formats and check if date is at least valid with one of them instead;

Comment: No, it doesn't do that.  There's just a bug with those specific formats.  It *should* work.